# How to convert value to user-inputted type?

Tags: python, types, type-conversion

Say I have a function where it converts `8` to a user-inputted type:

```
def convert_8_to_type(to_type):
```

What do I use to convert it to `to_type`?
Something like this:

```
to_type(8)
```

except I would like it to properly work (given `to_type` isn't a function). I could just put a large `if ... else if ...` statement, as in this:

```
if to_type == int:
    return int(8)
else if to_type == float:
    return float(8)
else if to_type == Decimal:
    return Decimal(8)
else if to_type == str:
    return str(8)
else if to_type == bool:
    return bool(8)
else if to_type == bytes:
    return bytes(8)
```

But then what if the user tries to convert to a type I have explicitly provided in the conversion table? The most effective would probably be to have it simply return (in this case) 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`to_type` is indeed a function if that's what the caller passes in:

```
def convert_8_to_type(to_type):
   return to_type(8)
```

```
>>> print(convert_8_to_type(bytes))
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Deriving the type from a `str` that names the type is another problem entirely, but from your code example it looks like you're getting the actual type, not its name as a string (e.g. you have `to_type == int`, not `to_type == 'int'`), so this should "just work".

Comment: I didn't realize that when I inputted those types it inputted as functions, or that they could be ran that way.

Comment: Always try running your code at least once before deciding it doesn't work!  :)

Comment: @CATboardBETA You're doing a lot of extra work if you're converting user input strings to type constructors. See my answer for an alternate approach. The answer you've accepted will still require a big `if` branch, and will still require you to deal with unsupported conversions.

Comment: @blorgon It actually deals with unsupported type conversions well enough for me.